# R Shiny - Using selectInput() selection to refer to column(s) of an uploaded data frame

Tags: r, shiny

I'm currently playing around with a Shiny Dashboard to look at the quality of a GPS session. Let me preface this by saying that I understand the code below is not pretty or efficient - I'm still quite new to Shiny.

Basically, I am trying to use the selection from selectInput to create a new dataframe (`flagged`) from an existing one (`data2`).

The goal of this, as you see, is to group each quality metric (`Hacc`, `Hdop`, & `Satellites`) into runs of quality tiers (`Deficient`, `Poor`, & `Moderate`) and show these grouped runs in a table with associated time.

Now, this is achieved perfectly fine when directly referring to each of the metrics within the code creating `flagged`. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to use the selected value `input$val` in lieu of the specific metrics.

It's difficult to provide data to reproduce here (as it's a large raw dataset), so I'm just initially seeing whether there is anything glaringly obvious I am doing wrong.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(gt)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

options(shiny.maxRequestSize=50*1024^2)

my_data <- as.data.frame(cbind("Hacc", "Hdop", "Satellites"))

ui <- fluidPage(

  br(),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      fileInput(
        inputId = "filedata",
        label = "Upload data file (.csv)", 
        accept = c(".csv")),
      
      selectInput("var", 
                  label = "Choose a session quality variable",
                  choices = c("Hacc_bin",
                              "Hdop_bin",
                              "Satellites_bin"),
                  selected = "Hacc_bin"),
      
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("DataTable"),
      textOutput("mytext")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  options(digits.secs = 2)
  values <- reactiveValues(df_data = NULL)
  
  data<-reactive({
    req(input$filedata)
    read.csv(input$filedata$datapath, header = TRUE)%>% 
      rename(Velocity = 'Speed..m.s.',
             Player = 'Player.Display.Name',
             Signal_quality = 'Quality.of.Signal',
             Satellites = 'No..of.Satellites'
      ) %>%
      select(-'Heart.Rate..bpm.', -'Accl.X', -'Accl.Y', -'Accl.Z',
             -'Instantaneous.Acceleration.Impulse', - 'Gyro.Yro.X', -'Gyro.Y', -'Gyro.Z') %>%
      mutate(Hdop_bin = cut(Hdop, 
                            breaks=c(0, 2, 3, 5, 10, 15), 
                            labels=c("Excellent", "Good", "Moderate", "Poor", "Deficient"),
                            include.lowest = TRUE),
             Hacc_bin = cut(Hacc, breaks=c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10), 
                            labels=c("Excellent", "Good", "Moderate", "Poor", "Deficient"),
                            include.lowest = TRUE),
             Signal_bin = cut(Signal_quality, breaks=c(0, 180, 220, 260, 300, 500), 
                              labels=c("Deficient", "Poor", "Moderate", "Good", "Excellent"), 
                              include.lowest = TRUE),
             Satellites_bin = cut(Satellites, breaks=c(0, 12, 14, 16, 18, 25), 
                                  labels=c("Deficient", "Poor", "Moderate", "Good", "Excellent"),
                                  include.lowest = TRUE))
    
    
  })
  
  tmp <- reactive({as.character(strptime(data$Time,'%H:%M:%OS'))
    
  })
  
  data2 <- reactive({data()%>%
      mutate(TimeInSec = as.numeric(strftime(as.character(strptime(Time,'%H:%M:%OS')),'%OS'))+60*as.numeric(strftime(as.character(strptime(Time,'%H:%M:%OS')),'%M'))+60*60*as.numeric(strftime(as.character(strptime(Time,'%H:%M:%OS')),'%H')))%>%
      mutate(TimeInSec = TimeInSec + rep(seq(0.00,0.09, by = 0.01), nrow(data())/10))
    
  })
  
  
  flagged <- reactive({setDT(data2())[, grp:= rleid(as.character(input$var))][input$var == "Deficient"|input$var == "Poor"|input$var == "Moderate", 
                                                                              .(start_time = paste(seconds.to.hms(TimeInSec[1]), 
                                                                                                   str_pad(as.character(round(TimeInSec[1] %% 1*100),2), 2, pad="0"), 
                                                                                                   sep="."),
                                                                                end_time = paste(seconds.to.hms(TimeInSec[.N]), 
                                                                                                 str_pad(as.character(round(TimeInSec[.N] %% 1*100),2), 2, pad="0"), 
                                                                                                 sep="."),
                                                                                duration_sec = round(TimeInSec[.N]-TimeInSec[1] + 0.01, 1),
                                                                                duration_min = round(round(TimeInSec[.N]-TimeInSec[1] + 0.01, 1)/60, 2),
                                                                                quality = input$var[.N]), 
                                                                              .(grp)]
  })
  
  output$DataTable <- renderTable({tail(flagged())
  })
    
  output$mytext <- renderText({
    input$var
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What I want (1) & What is currently happening (2):

[image: What I want]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like most likely the problem lies in using `input$var` in `data.table` object, i.e. the problem is rather in `flagged` reactive. For me the most suspicious is this part:

```
quality = input$var[.N]
```

I have made some tests in much simpler example, using the code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(gt)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

options(shiny.maxRequestSize=50*1024^2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  br(),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      fileInput(
        inputId = "filedata",
        label = "Upload data file (.csv)", 
        accept = c(".csv")),
      
      selectInput("var", 
                  label = "Choose a session quality variable",
                  choices = c("Hacc_bin",
                              "Hdop_bin",
                              "Satellites_bin"),
                  selected = "Hacc_bin"),
      
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("DataTable"),
      textOutput("mytext")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  options(digits.secs = 2)
  values <- reactiveValues(df_data = NULL)
  
  data<-reactive({
    
    data.table(Hacc_bin = 1,
               Hdop_bin = 2,
               Satellites_bin = 3)
    
  })
  

  flagged <- reactive({
    data()[, .(test = .SD[.N]), .SDcols = input$var]
  })
  
  output$DataTable <- renderTable({tail(flagged())
  })
  
  output$mytext <- renderText({
    input$var
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

and looking at the `flagged` reactive:

```
  flagged <- reactive({
    data()[, .(test = .SD[.N]), .SDcols = input$var]
  })
```

I have tried two thing - the code above (which works) and the following code (which does not work):

```
flagged <- reactive({
    data()[, .(test = input$var[.N])]
  })
```

Actually, it *works*, but not in expected way (so that's a little different than in your example where you just have an empty table, i.e. 0 rows.

However, if you want, you can try and change in your code this:

```
quality = input$var[.N]), 
                                                                              .(grp)]
```

Into this:

```
quality = .SD[.N]), 
                                                                              .(grp), .SDcols = input$var]
```

And let me know if this makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks for the response @gss, it's much appreciated. Unfortunately, it's now throwing a warning: `Error in [.data.table: All items in j=list(...) should be atomic vectors or lists.` Is there perhaps a more appropriate method of implementing `rleid` that will then allow easier use of `input$var`? As I mentioned in the post, I appreciate that my code is quite rough.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not able to help you with `data.table` itself :(